# tooltip on category axis in c3.js chart?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

I have a rotated bar chart, where I want to show categories on the x-axis. But big texts are being clustered in the axis. I wanted to truncate the text and show a tooltip instead.

Here is the chart code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250, 300]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {rotated: true,
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['cat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'cacat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat2', 'catcat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3', 'cat1aaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaa', 'cat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'cat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9', 'asas']
        },
        y: {
            show: false
        }
    }
});
```

One can check the code execution on [c3.js docs](https://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the multiline option

https://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-multilineMax

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250, 300]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    axis: {rotated: true,
        x: {
            tick: {
             multiline: true,
             multilineMax: 1,
           },
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['cat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'cacat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat2', 'catcat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa3', 'cat1aaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssssssssssaaaaaaaaa', 'cat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'cat1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9', 'asas']
        },
        y: {
            show: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Multiline is always set to 'true' in default. And it does not satisfy all requirements. I have posted the answer below or [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450416/8350914]

Comment: yes, but the multilinemax value is by default set to 2, that's what's causing the text wrap. Set it to 1 and you get the truncation and not the wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the perfect answer. This will truncate the column name if exceeds the limit of 20 and further adds the tooltip for the column.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
    },
    axis: {
        rotated: true,
        x: {
            tick: {
                multiline: false,
                format: function (d) {
                    var catName = this.api.categories()[d];
                    if (catName.length > 20) {
                        catName = catName.slice(0,20)+"…";
                    }
                    return catName;
                }
            },
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['Travel and Hospitalityaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa','Life Science and Pharma', 'Saas and Cloud', 'Hi-tech Manufacturing', 'Software', 'Business Services', 'Govt/Public Sector', 'Energy', 'Manufacturing', 'Healthcare','Media','Internet','Retail','Biotech','Automobile','Consumer Goods','Financial Services']
        }
    },
    onrendered: function () {
        var self = this;
        d3.select(this.config.bindto)
            .selectAll(".c3-axis-x .tick text")
            .each(function (d) {
                var title = d3.select(this).select("title");
                if (title.empty()) {
                    title = d3.select(this).append("title");
                }
                title.text (self.api.categories()[d]);
            })
        ;
    }
});
```